# Callback to mutable self

Tags: rust

Is there a way (in rust) to send a mutable borrowed self to a callback without the `mem::replace` hack I am using in the following MWE? I am using rust stable (1.11.0).

```
use std::mem;

trait Actable {
    fn act(&mut self);
}

// Not Cloneable
struct SelfCaller {
    message: String,
    callback: Box<FnMut(&mut SelfCaller)>,
    // other stuff
}

impl Actable for SelfCaller {
    fn act(&mut self) {
        fn noop(_: &mut SelfCaller) {}
        let mut callback = mem::replace(&mut self.callback, Box::new(noop));
        callback(self);
        mem::replace(&mut self.callback, callback);
    }
}

impl Drop for SelfCaller {
    fn drop(&mut self) {/* unimiportant to the story */}
}

fn main() {
    fn change(messenger: &mut SelfCaller) {
        messenger.message = "replaced message".to_owned();
    }

    let mut messenger = SelfCaller {
        message: "initial message".to_owned(),
        callback: Box::new(change),
    };

    messenger.act();

    println!("{}", &messenger.message);
}
```

[Play](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=use%20std%3A%3Amem%3B%0A%0Atrait%20Actable%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20act(%26mut%20self)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Not%20Cloneable%0Astruct%20SelfCaller%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20message%3A%20String%2C%0A%20%20%20%20callback%3A%20Box%3CFnMut(%26mut%20SelfCaller)%3E%2C%20%2F%2F%20other%20stuff%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20Actable%20for%20SelfCaller%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20act(%26mut%20self)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fn%20noop(_%3A%20%26mut%20SelfCaller)%20%7B%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20callback%20%3D%20mem%3A%3Areplace(%26mut%20self.callback%2C%20Box%3A%3Anew(noop))%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20callback(self)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mem%3A%3Areplace(%26mut%20self.callback%2C%20callback)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20Drop%20for%20SelfCaller%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20drop(%26mut%20self)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20unimiportant%20to%20the%20story%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20change(messenger%3A%20%26mut%20SelfCaller)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20messenger.message%20%3D%20%22replaced%20message%22.to_owned()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20messenger%20%3D%20SelfCaller%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20message%3A%20%22initial%20message%22.to_owned()%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20callback%3A%20Box%3A%3Anew(change)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20messenger.act()%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20%26messenger.message)%3B%0A%7D%0A&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no way, *because it is unsafe to do so*. Here's an example that demonstrates why (requires a nightly compiler).

```
#![feature(fn_traits)]
#![feature(unboxed_closures)]

use std::mem;

trait Actable {
    fn act(&mut self);
}

struct SelfCaller {
    message: String,
    callback: Box<FnMut(&mut SelfCaller)>,
}

impl Actable for SelfCaller {
    fn act(&mut self) {
        let mut callback: &mut Box<FnMut(&mut SelfCaller)> = unsafe { mem::transmute(&mut self.callback) };
        println!("calling callback");
        callback(self);
        println!("called callback");
    }
}

struct Callback;

impl Drop for Callback {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("Callback dropped!");
    }
}

impl<'a> FnOnce<(&'a mut SelfCaller,)> for Callback {
    type Output = ();

    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(mut self, args: (&mut SelfCaller,)) {
        self.call_mut(args)
    }
}

impl<'a> FnMut<(&'a mut SelfCaller,)> for Callback {
    extern "rust-call" fn call_mut(&mut self, (messenger,): (&mut SelfCaller,)) {
        println!("changing callback");
        messenger.callback = Box::new(|messenger| {});
        println!("changed callback");
        messenger.message = "replaced message".to_owned();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let change = Callback;

    let mut messenger = SelfCaller {
        message: "initial message".to_owned(),
        callback: Box::new(change),
    };

    messenger.act();

    println!("{}", &messenger.message);
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
calling callback
changing callback
Callback dropped!
changed callback
called callback
replaced message
```

OK, so what's going on? First, I've written the implementation of `act` for `SelfCaller` in such a way that I *can* call the callback without `mem::replace`, using `mem::transmute` to get the compiler to generate a new lifetime disconnected from `self`.

Then, I've written a callback (using the struct `Callback`, since I needed a type that implements both `FnMut` and `Drop` to demonstrate the problem) that mutates the `SelfCaller` by changing its `callback` member. This has the effect of **dropping the previous callback**, which is the callback that is currently executing! If `Callback` contained data members, attempting to read them would cause undefined behavior, since they are now in deallocated memory (we dropped the whole `Box`).

---

By the way, in your code using `mem::replace`, callbacks cannot change the callback, since you restore the callback after the callback call ends.

Comment: Thanks! That's helpful. In my case, though, the callback member is meant to be unchangeable. If the SelfCaller.callback member is hidden from the callbacks would it be acceptable to do this?

Comment: Yes, if the `callback` member is not public and there is no public method that changes it, then it's safe to cheat on the lifetime. Be sure to leave a comment or two in your code to document the fact that the `callback` member should not be modifiable by users, so that nobody adds a mutator method in the future!

Answer (score 2):

**No**, this is not possible with your code. If it were possible, you could easily construct an example that destroys memory safety, by for example accessing freed memory (*this is left as an exercise for the reader* ).

You could think about whether or not the `FnMut` really needs all of the fields of `SelfCaller`. If not, you can pass the (hopefully few) single fields as arguments. If not, you can create another type (let's call it `Inner`) that contains all fields important to the callback and pass it to the function.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need callbacks that borrow an environment, you can use a function instead of the closure:

```
trait Actable {
    fn act(&mut self);
}

struct SelfCaller {
    message: String,
    callback: fn(&mut SelfCaller),
}

impl Actable for SelfCaller {
    fn act(&mut self) {
        (self.callback)(self);
    }
}

fn main() {
    fn change(messenger: &mut SelfCaller) {
        messenger.message = "replaced message".to_owned();
    }

    let mut messenger = SelfCaller {
        message: "initial message".to_owned(),
        callback: change,
    };

    messenger.act();

    println!("{}", &messenger.message);
}
```

Comment: Whoops! I forgot to make SelfCaller implement Drop!